# Por qué me arroja el alert de "error"?, sin embargo, me inserta los datos

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Utilizando Ajax y PHP estoy haciendo un insert mediante el método POST, tengo los archivos distribuidos de la siguiente manera

> root/secciones/dependencias.php

```
<form id="frm_depe" method="POST">


 <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
         <button type="submit" id="btn_guardar" name="btn_guardar" class="btn btn-success">Guardar</button>
     </div>
</form>
```

este mismo archivo cuenta también con un pequeño script para cuando se da click al botón guardar

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn_guardar").on('click', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        agregar();
        
    });
});
```

> root/config/dependencias.php

```
require './bd.php';

$clave = $_POST['clave'];
$direccion = $_POST['direccion'];
$depe_ciclo = $_POST['depe_ciclo'];

$insertar = pg_prepare($conn,"insert_depe","INSERT INTO dependencias(clave, direccion, depe_ciclo) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)");
if ($clave){
$compare = pg_prepare($conn, "ver_depe", "SELECT * FROM dependencias WHERE clave = $1");
$compare = pg_execute($conn, "ver_depe", array($clave));
$resultado  =pg_fetch_assoc($compare);
if($resultado == False){
    $insertar =  pg_execute($conn, "insert_depe", array($clave,$direccion,$depe_ciclo));
}else{
    echo "algo salio mal";
}
}
```

Hago una pequeña condicion para evitar que se ingrese la misma dependencia a la base de datos

> root/JS/depe_fn.js

```
function agregar(){

var datos = $("#frm_depe").serialize();

$.ajax({
    method:"POST",
    url:"../config/dependencias.php",
    data: datos,
    success: function(e){
        if(e==1){
            alert("Registro exitoso");
        }else{
            alert("Error de registro");
            console.log(datos)
        }
    }
});
return false;
}
```

Comment: Diría que es porque en ningun caso `e==1` según veo en tu php.  Solo devuelves "algo salio mal" o bien nada, y eso no es **1** en ningun caso.

Comment: e no devuelve 1 o 0, deberias buscar como manejar los mensajes de ajax, hasta la que recuerdo esta success: y error: verifica eso